# SQL calculate opening and closing balances per week / month

Tags: cumulative-sum

everyone.

I have a question that I'm pretty sure has been answered somewhere else but I want to ask it anyway.

I have a base 'master' table that contains data at the very basic day level. From here I need to calculate opening base and closing base numbers for week / month (will be different views). These values use a field called CREATE_DATE. Below is a sample of the select statement.

```
select
    date_trunc(week, current_timestamp::date) as CURRENTWEEK,
    CREATE_DATE,
    MASTER_TENANT,
    TENANT,
    SALES_CHANNEL,
    GROUPING,
    PRODUCT,
    DEAL,
    SIM_TYPE,
    PORT_IN_STATUS,
    CHURN_REASON,
    OPENING_BASE,
    count_if(ACTIVATION_DATE::date is not null and TERMINATION_DATE::date is null) as ACTIVATIONS, -- activations per tenant for the week / month
    count_if(TERMINATION_DATE::date is not null) as CHURN, -- terminations per tenant for the week / month
    AGE_0_TO_1_MONTH,
    AGE_2_TO_5_MONTHS,
    AGE_6_TO_12_MONTHS,
    AGE_12_MONTHS_PLUS
from <DATABASE>.<SCHEMA>.<TABLE> -- BASE 'MASTER' TABLE
group by
    MASTER_TENANT,
    TENANT,
    SALES_CHANNEL,
    GROUPING,
    PRODUCT,
    DEAL,
    SIM_TYPE,
    PORT_IN_STATUS,
    CHURN_REASON,
    OPENING_BASE,
    ACTIVATION_DATE,
    TERMINATION_DATE,
    AGE_0_TO_1_MONTH,
    AGE_2_TO_5_MONTHS,
    AGE_6_TO_12_MONTHS,
    AGE_12_MONTHS_PLUS;
```

How would I go about calculating opening and closing values for week / month? I.e. This week's opening balance is last week's closing. How do I go about calculating the closing base?